# Disadvantages to high make job values

Tags: makefile, cmake

Is there any disadvantage to using a higher job value `-j` in make?

In most installation READMEs, it is suggested to use `make -j8` for 8 jobs to speed up the process. I am curious as to the disadvantages of simply using more jobs, for example `make -j16`. When I tried it, it seemed to work fine. Is there any problem with using higher values? Why do most projects use -j8 as the suggested value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Barring errors in the prerequisite statements in your makefile, there's no *correctness* issue with using higher `-j` values.  However, there are definitely *performance* concerns.  There's no free lunch and your build will not just continue to get faster forever the higher your `-j` value.  At some point not only will you not get any more improvement but you will actually get *increased* build times, just the same as when you run too many programs on your system at the same time, they all slow down.

There's no reason to choose 8 in particular, and anyplace that suggests that as a hardcoded value that is always the best should be dismissed as a useful resource: they are merely parroting something they heard from someone else, or came up with themselves, without understanding what it means.

The real value that works well depends very heavily on (a) your hardware, (b) your operating system, and (c) the kinds of commands being invoked by your recipes.

For example, if you have a single-core, or even a dual-core, system then using `-j8` will likely not work well for you.  That means eight different compilers all competing for the limited CPU resources at the same time, which means the operating system will be swapping them in and out constantly (which takes time) rather than letting them run to completion without context switches.  On systems with 24 cores, running `-j8` would leave most of them idle.

So does that mean that a 1-to-1 correspondence between cores and jobs is best?  It's a good starting point, but there are other things to consider.  First, other things run on your computer as well, so maybe cores-1 is better?  Second, compilers also have to read from and write to the disk and disk access is very slow (compared to CPU), so while one compiler job is waiting for disk I/O, other compiler jobs could be doing useful CPU work, so maybe cores+1 or cores+2 is better?  Third, some kinds of compiles are very CPU intensive while others are not: for example, compiling C++ with lots of templates, virtualized class hierarchies, inlines, and high optimization levels use lots of CPU; compiling C with its very straightforward, comparatively, compilation model takes much less CPU (and hence the ratio of I/O to CPU is higher and more jobs can run in parallel).

So what should you use?  The only way to know for certain is do tests: run your build with increasing values of `-j` until times either plateau, or start to increase.

I typically use "cores + 2" for a system with 4 to 8 cores (common these days).  If you have LOTS of cores you might try something like "cores + 0.4*cores", or whatever.

Comment: Did you mean to say increased build times?