# Optimizing make with the -j option

Tags: compilation, makefile

The `make` command has a `-j` option that allows you to specify how many concurrent jobs you want to have running. I heard somewhere (in a class, so I can't provide a link with text proof) that the ideal number is # of CPU cores +1. Although this will only run #cores jobs at once, the '+1' has something to do with optimizing the build process when one of the jobs finishes.

Can anybody confirm that #cores+1 is the ideal option for the `-j` flag?

Comment: This was addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499070/gnu-make-should-j-equal-number-the-number-of-cpu-cores-in-a-system

Comment: Also you might find this discussion interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348343/disadvantages-to-high-make-job-values/17349734  Note that using +1 doesn't have anything to do with _optimizing the build process when one of the jobs finishes_; that "optimization" doesn't exist.  Someone just made that up :)